# Allocate order quantity to multiple stock location product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stock table and order table… In stock, items are stored in location wise.. i.e. same items can be put in different locations… And I have orders for same product, and we need to allocate items from stock to orders location wise.

```
declare @stock TABLE 
(
    product VARCHAR(10),
    location varchar(10),
    quantity bigint     
)

insert into @stock values('CPU', 'loc1', 10)
insert into @stock values('CPU', 'loc2', 8)
insert into @stock values('CPU', 'loc3', 6)

declare  @Order TABLE
(
    orderid int,
    product varchar(10),
    OrderQuanity bigint
)

insert into @Order values(1, 'CPU',10)
insert into @Order values(2, 'CPU',10)
insert into @Order values(3, 'CPU',1)
```

and I need the result like as follows:

```
OrderID Product StockLocation   Order_QtyToBe_Allocated
1       CPU     loc1               10
2       CPU     loc2                8
2       CPU     loc3                2
3       CPU     loc3    1
```

See sometimes I need quantity needs to be picked from multiple location. And sometimes we need to allocate same location quantity to multiple orders.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to get what you want (I'm not sure about the Order_QtyToBeAllocated field as that's not in your schema, but I can help if you provide details.

Points.  Your schema is poor.  You need to include a primary in both tables and join on them.  Using a description/text field is bad practice.  You should also add a location table and use a lookup for that too.  I can help with this if you want?

Using your schema:

```
SELECT 
    orderid,
    o.product,
    location,
    SUM(OrderQuanity) [OrderQuantity]
FROM 
    @order o
INNER JOIN @stock s ON s.product = o.product
GROUP BY
    orderid,
    o.product,
    location
```

Comment: Thanks Stuart for your comments. Actually I was posting a simplest schema so that readers can understand my issue quickly. Order_QtyToBeAllocated should be a calculated field wherein we should get the quantity to be allocated to each order from the multiple stock location, wherein the same goods are stored. Your above joins just give me 9 rows which is not we actually wanted. I just wanted 4 rows as mentioned in my description above. Please check above.

Comment: OK.  I can sort of see what you're asking here, but have no idea how you're getting a CPU count in two locations of 8 and 2.  Can you explain that first?

Comment: 1 CPU loc1 10 <- This I understand
2 CPU loc2 8 <- This I understand
2 CPU loc3 2 <- This I don't get.  Unless it's you started with 10, 8 when into the first order which means there's 2 in the second order as you're short stocked.
3 CPU loc3 1 <- This I understand

Comment: Loc1 expired when Order 1 is allocated.
For Order 2, we need to get 8 from Loc2 and 2 from Loc 3 (to satisfy order quantity 10).
i.e. why 2 CPU loc3 2.

Comment: OK.  I understand.  Unfortunately this is going to be a pretty big query and something I really can't do right now.  Your software should be flagging the order as expired in the table, and the query should be able to just omit expired orders.   THink about how much work this will have to do if your data gets massive, and you have multiple expired orders?  You need to use some business logic and design your schema appropriately.

Comment: If an order expires when an order is made against the same location for the same part, your app should be able to execute a query like UPDATE orders SET ord_expired = 1 WHERE ord_locationid = x AND ord_productid = y AND ord_expired = 0.